# How do I find the count of concatenated columns of int and string data types in SQL CE?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, string-concatenation

How to merge different data type of column on SQL?

I have a table:

```
+-----------+-------------+
+ Column    + Data Type   +
+-----------+-------------+
+ Day       + Int         +
+ Time      + Varchar     +
+ Quota     + Int         +
+-----------+-------------+
```

I want to merge all of the column on that table.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT Day + ' - ' + Time + ' : ' + Quota AS [Description], COUNT(*) AS [Total] 
FROM table
GROUP BY Day + ' - ' + Time + ' : ' + Quota
```

The error message: `Data Conversion Failed. [ OLE DB status value (if known) = 2 ]`

When I tried to merge only the same data type, that is: `Day` and `Quota`, it's work. How can I do that?

Comment: You need to convert the ints to varchars. So Select CONVERT(Day, varchar) + Time + CONVERT(Quota, varchar) should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Columns of data type int should be converted or type cast to string data type like `VARCHAR` to perform string concatenation.

[**Click this link to view the demo in SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b339c/2)

*Script*: Tested in SQL Server 2012.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
(
    [Day] int NOT NULL
  , [Time] varchar NOT NULL
  , [Quota] int NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable ([Day], [Time], [Quota]) VALUES
    (1, '2', 101),
    (1, '1', 101),
    (2, '3', 101),
    (2, '3', 101),
    (3, '4', 263);

SELECT  Description
    ,   COUNT(Description) AS DescriptionCount
FROM
(
    SELECT  CAST([Day] AS VARCHAR) 
            + ' - ' + Time 
            + ' : ' + CAST([Quota] AS VARCHAR) AS [Description] 
    FROM    dbo.MyTable
) T1
GROUP BY Description;
```

*Output*:

```
DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTIONCOUNT
----------- ----------------
1 - 1 : 101        1
1 - 2 : 101        1
2 - 3 : 101        2
3 - 4 : 263        1
```

## UPDATE

*SQL Compact Edition version of the query*:

```
SELECT      LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(Day)))  + ' - ' + 
            LTRIM(RTRIM(Time))      + ' : ' + 
            LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(Quota))) AS Description
        ,   COUNT(*) AS DescriptionCount
FROM        MyTable
GROUP BY    LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(Day)))  + ' - ' + 
            LTRIM(RTRIM(Time))      + ' : ' + 
            LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(Quota)))
```

*Output*:

[image: sql ce output]

Answer (score 3):

This is a mashup of my answer and Siva's, hopefully it will solve the asker's problem:

[SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/89451/1)

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    iDay int NOT NULL
  , sTime varchar(50) NOT NULL
  , iQuota int NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO MyTable (iDay, sTime, iQuota) VALUES
    (1, '2', 101),
    (1, '1', 101),
    (2, '3', 101),
    (2, '3', 101),
    (3, '4', 263);

SELECT CAST(iDay AS VARCHAR) + ' - ' + sTime + ' : ' +
CAST(iQuota AS VARCHAR) AS Description
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY CAST(iDay AS VARCHAR) + ' - ' + sTime + ' : ' +
CAST(iQuota AS VARCHAR)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But it doesn't work. Still work the Siva code. Thanks anw :)

Answer (score 1):

*(Assuming MySQL)*:

You are trying to perform addition on strings and integers. `+` is not a concatenation operator in mysql. The error you get is telling you that the string could not be converted to a numeric type.

Try this:

```
SELECT concat(Day, ' - ', Time, ' : ', Quota) AS `[Description]`, COUNT(*) AS `[Total]`
FROM table
GROUP BY `[Description]`
```

Comment: Thanks @Siva, it works in MySQL so I wrongly assumed it will work everywhere :)

Comment: Actually MySQL is very flexible in its *group by* interpretations, I suspect this won't work on most other DBMS - your assertion is probably correct in the general case

Answer (score 0):

When you do the GROUP BY just write the field names. So...

SELECT Day + ' - ' + Time + ' : ' + Quota AS [Description], COUNT(*) AS [Total]
FROM table 
GROUP BY Day, Time, Quota

Does that work?

Comment: No, it doesn't. The problem is not on Group By. This problem has been solved. Thanks anw :)